# lumen queue connection, database driver

Tags: php, laravel, queue, lumen

Im struggling to configure the queue connection in lumen 8 project,
im my database.php i have 2 connections lets say A and B, A to connect to **DB_A** and B for **DB_B**.

my **database.php** looks like this :

```
// database.php
'connections' => [
    'connection_A' => array(
        'driver' => env('DB_A',''),
        'host' => env('DB_A_HOST',''),
        'port' => env('DB_A_PORT',''),
        'database' => env('DB_A_DATABASE',''),
        'username' => env('DB_A_USERNAME',''),
        'password' => env('DB_A_PASSWORD',''),
        'charset'  => 'utf8',
        'prefix' => '',
        'schema' => 'public',
    ),

    'connection_B' => array(
        'driver' => env('DB_B',''),
        'host' => env('DB_B_HOST',''),
        'port' => env('DB_B_PORT',''),
        'database' => env('DB_B_DATABASE',''),
        'username' => env('DB_B_USERNAME',''),
        'password' => env('DB_B_PASSWORD',''),
        'charset'  => 'utf8',
        'prefix' => '',
        'schema' => env('DB_B_SCHEMA'),
    ),
```

i use the connection A to fetch some data from DB_A and run a job using database driver on DB_B
so my tables jobs,failed_jobs are both in DB_B

i configured my **queue.php** like this

```
// queue.php
'connections' => [
   
    'database' => [
        'driver' => 'database',
        'table' => 'jobs',
        'queue' => 'default',
        'retry_after' => 90,
        'connection' => 'connection_B', // not working => table jobs not found
        'database' => 'connection_B', //  not working => table jobs not found
    ],

],

'failed' => [
    'driver' => 'database',
    'database' => 'connection_B', // works for some reason
    'table' => 'failed_jobs',
],
```

so my question is how to tell the the queue what database connection to use ?

i tried to force the connection before dispatching the job like this :

```
Config::set('database.connections.connection_B.database', env('DB_B_DATABASE'));
Config::set('database.connections.connection_B.schema', env('DB_B_SCHEMA'));
DB::purge('connection_B');
DB::reconnect('connection_B');
```

and i also tried to set the queue connection like this :

```
$connection = Queue::connection('connection_B');
$connection->pushOn('my_queue', $job);
```

i get an exception

```
No connector for []. {"exception":"[object] (InvalidArgumentException(code: 0): No connector for [].
```

am i missing or misunderstanding something ?

ps : in my app.php i load the queue.php and database.php.

```
$app->configure('app');
$app->configure('database');
$app->configure('queue');
```

and i dispatch my job like this :

```
$jobId = Queue::push((new CreatePdfJob($datas)),null,'my-queue');
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Did you migrate fot table creation?

Comment: yes , i used the command php artisan queue:table to create the migration and  php artisan migrate --database=connection_B to run it on the data base B

Comment: Do you see it in database? If not - try to set connection in migration file by override connection propertt

Comment: yes , i can see the jobs table and failed_jobs, the tables are where they should be, also both connection works fine ican get / save data . my question is somehting like in the arrays  'database'  what key to put to tell the queue what connection to use ? is it 'connection' like redis config or 'database' like the failed, or something else ?

Comment: Oh, you must use `database` connection name, array key in `queue.connections`. Or rename in to `database_B`

Comment: well im totaly lost for some reason if i try to query jobs and failed_jobs : 
**DB::connection('connection_B')->table('jobs')->get();** i get the error table jobs not found
**DB::connection('connection_B')->table('my-schema.jobs')->get();** works  
**DB::connection('connection_B')->table('failed_jobs')->get();** works without mentioning the schema

and in my connection_B i have set the right schema.
any idea whats going on why lumen cant find jobs table without forcing the schema ?

Answer (score 0):

i solved the issue in the queue.php

```
'connections' => [
    'database' => [
        'driver' => 'database',
        'table' => 'jobs',
        'queue' => 'default',
        'retry_after' => 90,
        'connection' => 'connection_B', // this works
    ],
```

im blind idiot i typed connnection with 3n , i also cleared the cache and cache config i dont know if it helped or not.

Thank you.